# pm2-logrotate install on offline linux machine

Tags: pm2, pm2-logrotate

I want to install pm2-logrotate on linux machine where the machine is not having internet connectivity

https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2-logrotate

Answer (score 2):

1.Download source code tar.gz [pm2-logrotate](https://github.com/keymetrics/pm2-logrotate/releases)

2.Install modules in code, Copy code to the same server environment(in network)

```bash
tar -xzvf pm2-logrotate-2.7.0.tar.gz
cd pm2-logrotate-2.7.0/
npm install
tar -czvf pm2-logrotate.tar.gz pm2-logrotate-2.7.0
```

3.Copy pm2-logrotate.tar.gz to offline server to .pm2/modules

```bash
cd ~/.pm2/modules/
tar -xzvf pm2-logrotate.tar.gz
pm2 module:generate pm2-logrotate
cd pm2-logrotate
pm2 install .
```

4.Add conf in to .pm2/module_conf.json

```json
{ 
   "pm2-logrotate": {
        "max_size": "10M",
        "retain": "30",
        "compress": false,
        "dateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD_HH-mm-ss",
        "workerInterval": "30",
        "rotateInterval": "0 0 * * *",
        "rotateModule": true
    },
    "module-db-v2": {
        "pm2-logrotate": {}
    }

}
```

Run pm2 conf pm2-logrotate can see pm2-logrotate config

Reset conf

```bash
pm2 set pm2-logrotate:max_size 100M
```

Answer (score 1):

To make an offline installer, you need to make your own `tar.gz` file.

First, you need to download the `Source code (tar.gz)` from [Pm2 GitHub](https://github.com/keymetrics/pm2-logrotate/releases/tag/2.7.0)

Extract the `tar.gz` file and this will create a folder with the source inside

Rename the main folder (normally named `pm2-logrotate-2.7.0`) to `module` and create the `pm2-logrotate-2.7.0.tar.gz` file again with the `module` folder

The struct of the files inside of the `tar.gz` will be something like:

```
module
|- .gitignore
|- CHANGELOG.md
|- README.md
|- app.js
|- node_modules
|- package-lock.json
|- package.json
|- pres
|- test
```

Then you can use the command `pm2 install pm2-logrotate-2.7.0.tar.gz` without getting errors

Comment: I know this is an old unanswered question but I think this might help someone like me who worked almost 1 day just doing this

Answer (score 0):

```
pm2 install pm2-logrotate-2.7.0.tgz
```